# Unable to Initialize Slider Control Variable in MFC Visual .NET 2008

Tags: variables, mfc, visual-studio-2008

I created an ordinary Vertical Slider variable in MFC Visual .NET 2008. When i try to initialize the Slider control variable which i call as "`m_VSliderBar`" through the following lines of codes

```
m_VSliderBar.SetRange(0, 100, TRUE);
m_VSliderBar.SetPos(0);
m_VSliderEcho.Format("%d", 0);
```

then the following error is output:

```
error C2664: 'void ATL::CStringT<BaseType,StringTraits>::Format(const wchar_t *,...)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [3]' to 'const wchar_t *'
```

I don't understand the error. Could someone help me compile the code properly?

Comment: Implementation issues belong on StackOverflow.  Programmers is for conceptual questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously have a Unicode build. Try this:

```
m_VSliderEcho.Format(_T("%d"), 0);
```

The error message is telling you that the `Format` function is expecting a `wchar_t` argument (i.e. a 16-bit character, which means Unicode) and you have supplied an ANSI string. The `_T()` macro prepends the correct modifier to a literal string depending on your project properties.

So for Unicode builds, this will translate to ;

```
m_VSliderEcho.Format(L"%d", 0);
```